Not able to handle UI When Keyboard appears after clicking on textInput
So below is the code which works in ios without any disturbance in UI when keyboard Appears. But in Android, I have issues handling keyboard after clicking on textInput.
return (
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: this.state.changeThemeSwitch ?
            helpers.whiteColor() : helpers.blackColor(),
          marginBottom: 10,
        }}>
          <CustomStatusBar />
          {this.renderHeader()}
          <View style={{
            justifyContent: "flex-end", alignItems: "flex-end",
            flex: 1,
          }}>

            <View
              style={{
                alignSelf: "flex-end",
                justifyContent: "flex-end", flexDirection: 'column',
                marginBottom: this.state.parentViewTopMargin,
                width: "100%",
              }}>

              <ScrollView
                ref={(ref) => this.scrollViewRef = ref}
                onLayout={() => {

                  if (this.scrollViewRef) {
                    this.scrollViewRef.scrollToEnd({ animated: false })
                  }
                }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">

                {messages &&
                  messages.map((item, index) =>
                    this.renderItem(item, index))}

              </ScrollView>

              <View style={{ ...styles.inputContainer }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showKeyboard}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faMicrophone}
                    size={30}
                    style={{
                      color: "#3A913F",
                    }}>
                  </FontAwesomeIcon>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TextInput ref={this.inputRef}
                  keyboardType='default'
                  multiline
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    backgroundColor: this.state.changeThemeSwitch ? helpers.whiteColor() : helpers.blackColor(),
                    color: this.state.changeThemeSwitch ? helpers.blackColor() : helpers.whiteColor(),
                    borderRadius: 6,
                    paddingHorizontal: 16,
                    paddingVertical: 8,
                    marginRight: 10,
                    borderWidth: 1.5,
                    borderColor: "#3A913F"
                  }}
                  placeholder="Type your query..."
                  placeholderTextColor={this.state.changeThemeSwitch
                    ? helpers.blackColor()
                    : helpers.whiteColor()}
                  value={message}
                  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ message: text })}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleSend}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faPaperPlaneTop}
                    size={30}
                    style={{
                      color: "#3A913F",
                    }}>
                  </FontAwesomeIcon>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );

I tried using KeyboardAvoidingView for android with behavior set as "padding" || "height", but none of them worked.
Am I missing some styles for the mainView in render or Is there any other way to solve this issue in android?

which version of react native you are using?

react-native-version: 0.61.5

Try wrapping your entire UI inside a KeyboardAvoidingView component.

this is react native, why did you add html tag here

Apologies for the confusion. Try wrapping your entire UI inside a KeyboardAvoidingView component see if that helps.

wrapped UI in keyboardavoidingview like this  still the issue is not fixed
